# What is the meaning of "人の身である" and "人あらざる"?

Tags: translation, meaning, words

> 私たちの悲願、奇跡に至ろうとする切望はどこからきたものなのか。私たちは何の為に、人の身であるままに、人あらざる地点に到達しようとしていたのか。

I'm having some problems with understanding not just the meaning of "人の身である" but the meaning of "人あらざる" too in the context behind them. Can someone explain for me in their respective context the meaning of these expressions/words?

Comment: Where is this sentence from?  Was it written this way, with spaces and those kanji?  Did you write it down yourself?

Comment: I write it by myself it's from here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3S_Zd3WLLJw

Comment: It seems that you are ascribing the word 飲み to the audio without any written documentation of such. Why not use のみ instead?

Comment: I edited the transcription and the question.  Please take a look.

Comment: ビデオ見られないです・・ blocked in your country だって・・

Answer (score 5):

> 「私たちは何{なん}の為{ため}に、人{ひと}の身{み}であるままに、人あらざる地点{ちてん}に到達{とうたつ}しようとしていたのか。」

身 ＝ 身分{みぶん} ＝ "social status", "rank", etc.

人の身であるままに　＝ "as mere humans"

あらざる ＝ ～でない ＝ "to not be"　あらざる is a literary/archaic version of ～でない

> "For what reason were we as (nothing but) mere humans trying to reach the point where we would no longer be humans?"